# How to catkin_make one package

Tags: ros, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install my custom ROS workspace from source.

What I've done is to download the source code of version of `ros-kinetic-ros-base`, then I add some additional packages into ros-base.

When I add one package, I always execute `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to catkin_make all packages. This gonna take much time.

So I'm thinking if I can catkin_make only one package that I added because others have been installed before.

For example, here is the structure of my `ros-base`:

/home/ros/
|-----------src
|-----------build_isolated
|-----------devel_isolated
|-----------install_isolated

As you see, all have been done correctly after executing `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. Now I add a package named `newPkg` into `./src`. To rebuild, I have to execute the command again, which will rebuild all packages.

So is it possible to catkin_make the only one package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285341/how-to-catkin_make-one-package/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check [#q54178](https://answers.ros.org/question/54178/how-to-build-just-one-package-using-catkin_make/).

Personnally I use `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar"`.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2